# Laravel testing, no such table, sqlite

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am running Laravel, on OS X using MAMP, and I am trying to do some unit testing, using PHPUnit, and sqlite, however when I run my tests, I get the error

> General error: 1 no such table: users

I've tried running the artisan, to manually migrate the database, using the --env=testing, which runs fine, however I still get the error. I even call `Artisan::call('migrate');` in the SetUp method.

/app/config/testing/database.php

```
return [
    'default' => 'sqlite',

    'connections' => [
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => ''
        ],
    ]
];
```

**EDIT:**
Migration file:

```
Schema::create('users', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email', 32)->unique();
    $table->string('password', 64);
    $table->string('username', 32)->unique();
    $table->dateTime('birthdate');
    $table->enum('status', array('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE'));
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('roles', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name', 32);
});

Schema::create('role_user', function ($table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('role_id');

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');

});
```

Comment: Can you show us your migration that create the table users ? Which DB do you use in the rest of your app ? MySQL ?

Comment: Yes, it's mysql, I will add the migration file when i get back to work.

Comment: Added the migration in the edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support the `ENUM` type : http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

That's why the users table isn't created. You will have to run your tests on a classic MySQL table or remove all the `ENUM` types.

Comment: Solved my problem, went with a "Enum" table instead. Thank you.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for the past 2 years

Answer (score 6):

Running migrations before running the test doesn't work because, as your config shows, you db is in *memory*, so every time you run a new test, it runs migrations for each testing session and completely destroys all testing data when it finishes.

To use the *memory* database, run your migrations each time you run your tests, extend your classes from TestCase with something like:

```
<?php

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

  public function createApplication()
  {
      $unitTesting = true;
      $testEnvironment = 'testing';
      return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
  }

  public function setUp()
  {
      parent::setUp();
      $this->prepareForTests();
  }
  private function prepareForTests()
  {
      Artisan::call('migrate');
      Artisan::call('db:seed');
  }
  public function tearDown()
  {
      parent::tearDown();
  }
}
```